# How to use minimize() from shadowJar properly?

Tags: gradle, shadowjar, fatjar

In my configuration I have:

```
shadowJar {
    minimize()
    archiveName = "fat.jar"
}
```

When I do fatjar, shadowJar doesn't includes my code from package `mystdeim`
I found in documentation that I can force to exclude some dependencies from minimize by `exclude(dependency('io.*:.*:.*'))`, but how to exclude my code from minimize task?

Comment: Did you use "application" plugin ? can you post all the gradle file ?